# Merge multiple rows in a data frame with different values

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

I'm new to R and I'd like to know how to merge multiple rows with same column values for most of the columns.

For ex: I have a dataset as:

```
      v1    v2    v3   v4 
      2     3     4    5
      2     3     5    NA
```

Now, I'd like to see the result as:

```
      v1    v2    v3   v4 
      2     3     NA    NA
```

I want the NA to be merged as is and fields that differ to be turned into NA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dataframe is `df`:

```
apply(df, 2, function(u) ifelse(length(unique(u))==1, u[1], NA))

#  v1 v2 v3 v4
#1  2  3 NA NA
```

To answer the **sub question**:

```
df = data.frame(col1=c(2,2,3),col2=c(3,3,3), col3=c(4,5,5), col4=c(5,NA,NA))

#  col1 col2 col3 col4
#1    2    3    4    5
#2    2    3    5   NA
#3    3    3    5   NA

rbind(apply(df[1:2,], 2, function(u) ifelse(length(unique(u))==1, u[1], NA)), 
      df[3:nrow(df),])

#  col1 col2 col3 col4
#1    2    3   NA   NA
#3    3    3    5   NA
```

Comment: `lapply` might make more sense for a `data.frame`, but this is otherwise a straightforward approach (+1).

Comment: Thank you @colonel-beauvel. My next question is: If I have the dataset like that of the above but I want to merge only those rows with same values for v1, how do you suggest I do it? (For example, assume the third row to be (3,3,5,NA) then the result should contain two rows: (2,3,NA,NA) and (3,3,5,NA))

Comment: The asnswer is edited, just use rbind to work on the first two line and concatenate with the other rows after treatment!

Comment: Your 2nd part hardcodes the row numbers. Basically, I want a group-by effect on col1. (I should've been more clear earlier, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

We could try `anyDuplicated` and `sweep` to get the expected output

```
unique(sweep(df1, 2,  NA^(sapply(df1, anyDuplicated)!=nrow(df1)),'*'))
#    v1 v2 v3 v4
#1    2  3 NA NA
```

#### Update

Based on the comments under @Colonel Beauvel's post, we could create a logical index from the 'mode' of 'v1', subset the dataset, do the above step, and `rbind`.

```
 df2 <- rbind(df1, c(3,3, 5, NA))

 Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 }

 indx <- with(df2, v1==Mode(v1))
 rbind(unique(sweep(df2[indx,], 2, NA^(sapply(df2[indx,], 
           anyDuplicated)!=nrow(df2[indx,])), '*')), df2[!indx,])
 #  v1 v2 v3 v4
 #1  2  3 NA NA
 #3  3  3  5 NA
```

Or

```
 df3 <- df2[indx,]
 rbind(sapply(df3, function(x) unique(x * 
                       NA^(anyDuplicated(x)!= nrow(df3)))), df2[!indx,])
  #  v1 v2 v3 v4
  #1  2  3 NA NA
  #3  3  3  5 NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c(2L, 2L), v2 = c(3L, 3L), v3 = 4:5,
v4 = c(5L, NA)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: @SanthoshHegde  I updated the post with the data I used

Comment: extremely far fetched and complex, but sweep is nice!

Comment: @SanthoshHegde Do you still get error by using the dput dataset?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Actually `anyDuplicated` would be fast, but the complexity is in converting the logical index to `NAs`.  Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package with your dataframe `data`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  summarise_each(funs(ifelse(length(unique(.))>1,"NA",.)))

  v1 v2 v3 v4
1  2  3 NA NA
```

If there are some of your variables that you want to group on, instead of merging, you can specify them as grouping variables:

```
data %>%
  group_by(v1, v2) %>% # the variables you want to group by
  summarise_each(funs(ifelse(length(unique(.))>1,"NA",.)))

Source: local data frame [1 x 4]
Groups: v1

  v1 v2 v3 v4
1  2  3 NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam. I encountered a problem with this. In my case, some columns are of "character" class, some are "numeric", and some are "factor". I'm trying to group by on ID which is numeric and NA fields are also on a numeric column. Now, your code gives an error as:  data %>%
+   group_by(id) %>% # the variables you want to group by
+   summarise_each(funs(ifelse(length(unique(.))>1,"NA",.)))
Error: not compatible with requested type